# postman.setNextRequest() executing all requests

Tags: postman

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var newUser = jsonData._id;

pm.environment.set("userId", newUser);


if(responseCode.code === 200)
{
postman.setNextRequest("Get Passenger");
}

else
{
postman.setNextRequest("Get Airlines");
}
```

I'm executing the above script but it runs both if and else both. But if I swap if and else they work fine

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

I guess you put the order of 3 requests in collection like this:

1. Request 1
2. Get Passenger
3. Get Airlines

The execution workflow would be:

```
Request 1 --> return status 200 --> request Get Passenger
```

In runner, postman will run request from head to toe. So, when it finished `Get Passenger`, the next request to run is `Get Airlines`. It doesn't relate to `if-else` in your code.

If you want to stop after request `Get Passenger` finish, you need add this code to stop runner.

```
postman.setNextRequest(null);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats the point, I need to execute in if else